# jQuery ajax makes extra get requests IE 11

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm getting a very strange happenings when I try to make an ajax request in IE 11. It makes the get request on the URL that I want but then makes another call without any kind of stimulus. I am positive no other requests are explicitly being made in the code.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: authorizeUrl,
  type: "GET",
  cache: false
})
.done(function(response) { //handle }}
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) { //handle }}
```

In the Network tab it makes a GET request with Initiator/Type XMLHttpRequest and status 200 response but then makes the new call to the root page with no Initiator/Type and it ends up with a 302 response.

I'm very confused and any help is welcome!

Comment: Check the url on the request that gets the 302 and the one that gets the 200.  A 302 is a form of redirect.

Comment: Yes. It redirects to another page that I don't want it to redirect to (a page with a 206 status). I'm trying to figure out why it's even making a request to the root page.